# React useEffect loads a component twice

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am having some issues when loading a container component. The component is fetching data from a API and then sends the data to a stateless component via props. The issue i am facing is that the container component loads twice. On the first load the data is empty and on the second load the data is there. I am getting a error when the stateless components gets loaded without any data, because it is expecting data. I have put an if statement in my code that checks if the data is loaded and this works, but i was wondering if there is way to do it without using the if statement.

I am using redux, redux thunks and axios.

container component

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // load articles only once
    if (isObjectEmpty(props.article)) {
      props.loadArticles().catch(error => {
        console.log("Loading articles failed" + error);
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

```
  // only load the component when we have data
  if (isObjectEmpty(props.article)) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Section>
        <PostPopulairSection articles={props.popularArticles} />
      </Section>
    </>
  );
};
```

The error i am getting from the stateless component:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3b4s.png)

Comment: You do need conditional rendering here. `useEffect` is not loading your component twice. First, the component loads by itself without any data; here, you can show a data loading message or a spinner. After the first load, `useEffect` runs and the data starts loading from the API. The loader is still visible at this stage. Once the data is loaded, the component re-renders, but with actual data. Now, hide the loader and display the data. Your `PostPopulairSection` component can handle this based upon the value of it's `props`.

Comment: you have to add `props` (specifically `article` and `loadArticle`) to your `useEffect`'s dependency list

Comment: Tried that, still getting the same error. I think i will have to go with conditional rendering.